# Музыкальный бот для Discord на Python

Tags: python, бот, discord

Написал музыкального бота, который при команде `-play (link)` входит в голосовой канал, но не включает музыку, а выдает ошибку

Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import pafy
import logging
import youtube_dl

logging.basicConfig(filename='bot.log', level=logging.INFO)

TOKEN = 'token'
PREFIX = '-'

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == 'привет':
        await message.channel.send('Привет!')
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        return await ctx.send("Вы не подключены к голосовому каналу!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        vc = ctx.voice_client

    video = pafy.new(url)
    best = video.getbestaudio()
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(best.url, method='fallback')

    vc.play(source)

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client:
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Бот не подключен к голосовому каналу.")
        
logging.info('Bot Online')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command play
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 815, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 836, in __extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 534, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 1794, in _real_extract
    'uploader_id': self._search_regex(r'/(?:channel|user)/([^/?&#]+)', owner_profile_url, 'uploader id') if owner_profile_url else None,
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 1012, in _search_regex
    raise RegexNotFoundError('Unable to extract %s' % _name)
youtube_dl.utils.RegexNotFoundError: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\main.py", line 37, in play
    info = ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False)
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 808, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 824, in wrapper
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 628, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 598, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "a:\Work\piton\discord3\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Обнови библиотеку youtube-dl до последней версии pip install --upgrade youtube_dl